# How to inform Spring 3.0.5 that the user has authenticated via OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Google stopped supporting OpenID at the end of April, and we need to migrate our application’s authentication system to OAuth2. Reading [Google’s guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#appsetup), it is straightforward to make OAuth requests and retrieve Google user information needed by our application.

However, our application makes significant use of Spring security 3.0.5, and so we have to integrate OAuth with Spring security. In the standard web application scenario, a Spring security context object is created automatically by Spring once the user has successfully logged in. Many JSP pages use Spring security tags to check if the user has logged in, or if the user is an admin user, and to determine the appropriate page contents to display.  It seems that Spring security oauth is the ideal framework to do the job.

During the development work, here are the problems I’m having:

1. After the user has approved access to their basic information on the Google oauth page, Google redirects the user back to our application’s page (pre-configured in the Google apps console). I can’t find a ‘Spring’ way to retrieve user information (although I can retrieve user information using Google APIs).
2. When Google redirects users back to our application, Spring security needs to know that the user has been successfully authenticated so that it can create a SecurityContext object. But so far I can’t find a way to let Spring security know this.

I can run Spring Oauth2 demo app tonr2 (github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/1.0.0.RELEASE/samples/oauth2/tonr) successfully. The demo asks the user to log in with a local username / password, then after clicking ‘access facebook friends’, the user is redirected to the facebook site, logs into facebook using oauth authentication and finally retrieves their friends list. However, we want to avoid the two authentication steps as stated above. Here is an example of a site that works how we would like (minus the local login box) — see http://lucy.me/login/auth.

Here is the code to read google user profile:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "google", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String google(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
  log.debug("Google OAuth filter trigger!");
  String c = request.getParameter("code");

  if(c==null || "".equals(c)) {
     // trigger google oauth2
  }else{
     ResponseEntity<Object> forEntity = googleRestTemplate.getForEntity("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo", Object.class);
  }
}
```

Comment: You need Spring Social for that. Check [this](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/adding-social-sign-in-to-a-spring-mvc-web-application-configuration/) which explains it for Facebook and Twitter, but it should be similar for Google (using Spring Social Google).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't!

*No user information travels over the wire - username nor password.* So you can't find it in the Spring context in your OAuth client application.

When a redirect comes from Google to your app, if the user authentication was successful, the redirect will come back with a stateKey and an authorization code that will allow Spring Security to ask for an access token. Once you get the access token, you can issue requests to the server on behalf of that user w/o knowing anything about him. This is the beauty of OAuth.

The state key mentioned earlier will bind the redirect to a context in your application.

It falls in your responsibilities to have a user context in your Spring OAuth client application that will be bound to the access token/refresh token you will get from the server (Google).

Of course you can query Google and get the username, if the user granted you with the permission to do so, but otherwise, the OAauth protocol will not allow you to collect any information about the user.

Here is the basic flow where authorization grant is used: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1

Comment: what i've done so far is to use oauth client redirecting users to google oauth page and Google returns stateKey and authz code. If I understand you correctly, I need to make the second call to get access code and create Spring security context **manually** (e.g. do an auto login) and then pull out google user information?

Comment: You don't have to initiate a second call to get the access token nor create the Spring OAuth context manually. That is handled by Spring OAuth itself.

Comment: @nucatus : can you tell me how can spring security will get access token from the authorization code, and we don't have to do it manually ? and how it will create a `principal` and add it to the current spring security context ??

Comment: Look at the `OAuth2RestTemplate#acquireAccessToken(OAuth2ClientContext oauth2Context)` method. More specific, this is where the access token is set into the oauth local context: `oauth2Context.setAccessToken(accessToken)`. The oauth context is an attribute of a princilap, if any `DefaultOAuth2ClientContext` and not a principal itself. If you need to persist the access token, you need to implement and wire a `ClientTokenServices` bean. There's a JDBC implementation you can use out of the box, `JdbcClientTokenServices`

Comment: @nucatus Hi, I've looked at OAuth2RestTemplate. Method acquireAccessToken is protected, so assuming it is called by other methods as needed. My code (appended above) gives me a 400 bad request error, any ideas?

Comment: @nucatus I can get Spring OAuth context by calling OAuth2RestTemplate.getOAuth2ClientContext() . However, what I need is the Spring security context, do I have to create Spring security context manually from OAuth context?